# mysql summary query with special condition

Tags: mysql

I Have tables like below
[image]

How is query to show summary data like above?

NB: I was try, but my query result INDIA is 3. What i mean is only count company on period without count project with that period, so that the right result should is 2 like above

Thank You

Comment: Can you share what you did? your query statement

Comment: select Country_Name, sum(jum) from (Select count(a.Country_Name) AS Jum, a.Country_Name
from Company a inner join Project b on a.id_company=b.id_company
where b.period='2017' 
group by a.id_company, b.period ) as test group by Country_Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2b7fa4218b55a6683637f39676e8d08e)**

```
Select countryname, count(distinct a.id_company) as sumval
from company a inner join project b on a.id_company=b.id_company 
where b.period='2017' 
group by countryname
```

OUTPUT:

```
countryname sumval
Franch        1
India         2
```